# Chained drop downs with ajax odd behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following dropdowns controls.
I am chaining them all together so when one is modified the next one will update conditionally:

```
<select name="building" id="building" onchange="getunit()">
  <option id="-1">Select building</option>
</select>
<select name="unit" id="unit" onchange="getlease()">
  <option id="-1">Select unit</option>
</select>
<select name="lease" id="lease" onchange="getleaseterm()">
  <option id="-1">Select lease</option>
</select>
   <select name="leaseterm" id="leaseterm">
  <option id="-1">Select lease term</option>
</select>
```

for 1st one- I populate everything without filtering

```
   $select = $('#building');
    //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/get_building/',
      dataType:'JSON',
      success:function(data){
        //clear the current content of the select
        //iterate over the data and append a select option

        $.each(data, function(key, val){
          $select.append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
        })
      },
    });
```

Other 3 they dependant from first one an each other

```
function getunit() {

    //get a reference to the select element
    $select = $('#unit');
    $lease = $('#lease');
    $leaseterm = $('#leaseterm');
    //request the JSON data and parse into the select element

    var c_id = ($("select[name='building'] option:selected").attr('value'));
    c_url = "/api/get_unit/"+c_id+"/";

    $.ajax({

      url: c_url,
      dataType:'JSON',
      success:function(data1){
        //clear the current content of the select
        $select.html('');

        $.each(data1, function(key, val){
          $select.append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.number + '</option>');
        })
        getlease();
      },

    });

}

function getlease() {

    //get a reference to the select element
    $select = $('#lease');
    $leaseterm = $('#leaseterm');
    //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
    var s_id = ($("select[name='unit'] option:selected").attr('value'));
    s_url = "/api/get_lease/"+s_id+"/";

    $.ajax({
      url: s_url,
      dataType:'JSON',
      success:function(data1){
        //clear the current content of the select
        $select.html('');
        //iterate over the data and append a select option

        $.each(data1, function(key, val){
          $select.append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.id + '</option>');
        })
      },

    });

}



function getleaseterm() {

    //get a reference to the select element
    $select = $('#leaseterm');
    //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
    var l_id = ($("select[name='lease'] option:selected").attr('value'));
    l_url = "/api/get_leaseterm/"+l_id+"/";

    $.ajax({
      url: l_url,
      dataType:'JSON',
      success:function(data1){
        //clear the current content of the select
        $select.html('');
        //iterate over the data and append a select option

        $.each(data1, function(key, val){
          $select.append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.id + '</option>');
        })
      },

    });

}
```

First 3 functions work like a clock. My problem is that the last function getleaseterm() do  not always picks up correct values.I really do not see problem in the code I am not getting any errors in console.

Comment: It's probably the backend that is at fault.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in this line:

```
var l_id = ($("select[name='lease'] option:selected").attr('value'));
```

An option doesn't have a value attribute. In your case you defined a **val** attribute. Hence, if you need to get this value you need to write:

```
var l_id = ($("select[name='lease'] option:selected").attr('val'));
```

As per documentation I'd suggest to use the standard [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) attribute.

In this case, you can get the selected value with:

```
$("select[name='lease']").val();
```

In any case, I'd suggest to separate the js code from html. But if you cannot, at least use the following parameters:

- this:  reference to the current element
- event:  the event object

So, your html will look like:

```
<select name="lease" id="lease" onchange="getleaseterm(this, event)">
```

In this way your function doesn't **get a reference to the select element**

In order to empty a select I'd sugest to use [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) instead of **.html('')**

```js
function getleaseterm(ele, e) {
    $select = $(ele);
    var l_id = $(ele).val();
    l_url = "/api/get_leaseterm/"+l_id+"/";

    // for testing....
    l_url = 'https://api.github.com/repositories?since=' + l_id;

    $.ajax({
        url: l_url,
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(data1){
            //clear the current content of the select
            $select.empty();
            //iterate over the data and append a select option

            $.each(data1, function(key, val){
                $select.append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.id + '</option>');
            })
        },

    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select name="building" id="building" onchange="getunit(this, event)" disabled>
    <option value="-1">Select building</option>
</select>
<select name="unit" id="unit" onchange="getlease(this, event)"  disabled>
    <option value="-1">Select unit</option>
</select>
<select name="lease" id="lease" onchange="getleaseterm(this, event)">
    <option value="-1">Select lease</option>
    <option value="11">364</option>
</select>
<select name="leaseterm" id="leaseterm"  disabled>
    <option value="-1">Select lease term</option>
</select>
```